# How to save tableview cell to UserDefaults and then show it

Tags: ios, swift

How can i save tableview cell to UserDefaults
I want make favorite page
When i click star button, cell must save on UserDefault
Please help me
I dont found good info about it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A cell subclass shouldn't be saved or archived , you need to save the model corresponding to the indexPath of this cell like when the cell is selected you do

```
let item = arr[indexPath.row]  // here save item
```

After that you load that item and show it again in that table cell